# Laravel 4: Using $this and Undefined variable: user_id

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm new with Laravel and I have some problem

First Problem: When I using $this-> in __construct function , and want to using it in a method Like this code:

```
// construct method
public function __construct() {
        $this->user_id = Auth::user()->id_user;
}
// another method 
    public function index()
    {


        $this->data['files'] = DB::table('mhd_cloud_transfer_files')->distinct()
                    ->where('mhd_cloud_transfer_files.to_transfer_file',$this->user_id )
                    ->where('mhd_cloud_transfer_files.folder_transfer_file',0)
                    ->orwhere(function($query){
                        $query->where('from_transfer_file', $this->user_id );
                        $query->where('to_transfer_file',0);
                    })
                    ->join('mhd_cloud_files', 'mhd_cloud_files.id_file', '=','mhd_cloud_transfer_files.id_file')
                    ->join('mhd_main_users', 'mhd_main_users.id_user', '=', 'mhd_cloud_files.author_file')
                    ->paginate(25);
 }
```

this error :

> ErrorException: Undefined variable: user_id

and another problem when I'm using $this-> in methods

in same problem this error:

> Using $this when not in object context

**This is All of my code (controller class)**
http://pastebin.com/eVbuknLd

Comment: Where are you using $this? Is the error referring to the code you posted, or to somewhere else?

Comment: @DamienPirsy I'm using it in public method in controller

Comment: Could you post a little more of your code? SO far looks correct

Comment: http://pastebin.com/eVbuknLd

Comment: You're using $this in context of closure (pay attention to `orwhere(function($query){` inside which you have `$this`, which isn't in scope of current object). It's not laravel problem, it's to do with knowing the syntax of PHP. If you want to refer to the object inside closures, you need to somehow make that object available to the closure - look up the `use` keyword when dealing with closures.

Comment: @N.B. better post that as an answer ;)

Comment: yes , it is right , I solved the problems , thanks

Answer (score 0):

**try adding `public var $user_id` to the class declaration.**

just remember to check `Auth::user()` for a `NULL` that indicates no user is logged in. unless you are sure you check it anywhere you use this class.

Comment: Auth::user()->id_user return id_user not null

Comment: it depand on name of colume in Database , In my user table it is called 'id_user'

Comment: If Auth::user() were null OP'd be getting `Trying to access property of a non-object` kind of error, not `Using $this when not in object context`. The latter happens if OP's using static methods, or if `$this` is outside the class.

Comment: Moreover, not declaring the variable , again, would lead to **another error**: `Undefined variable MyController::$user_id`, not `Using $this when not in object context`. And `public var` is a **syntax error** `syntax error, unexpected T_VAR, expecting T_VARIABLE `. C'mon.

Comment: Undefiend variable $user_id showing in each public method contraller when I using $this->user_id , but 'Using $this when not ..' showing also when I using $this-> for any thing